# Coefficient works on $\pi$, $x$ and $x^2$, but not on $\pi ^2$

Tags: expression-manipulation, coefficients

Consider

```
(\[Pi] + 2 \[Pi]^2 + 3 x + 4 x^2)
```

Executing

```
Coefficient[(\[Pi] + 2 \[Pi]^2 + 3 x + 4 x^2), #] & /@ {x, 
  x^2, \[Pi], \[Pi]^2}
```

returns

```
{3, 4, 1, 0}
```

Why does `Coefficient` not work with pi squared and how can I make it work (apart from replacing pi with y and looking at y squared)?

Mathematica 12.3.1 on Ubuntu

Comment: `Coefficient[(\[Pi] + 2 \[Pi]^2 + 3 x + 4 x^2), Pi, 2]`

Comment: oh, that is simple. But why does $x^2$ work then?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me (the behavior with `Pi^2` -- similar problem with other built-in numeric constants like `E`).